# Tuple slicing not returning a new object as opposed to list slicing

Tags: python, list, tuples, slice, cpython

In Python (2 and 3). Whenever we use list slicing it returns a new object, e.g.:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
print(id(l1))
l2 = l1[:]
print(id(l2))
```

Output

```
>>> 140344378384464
>>> 140344378387272
```

If the same thing is repeated with tuple, the same object is returned, e.g.:

```
t1 = (1,2,3,4)
t2 = t1[:]
print(id(t1))
print(id(t2))
```

Output

```
>>> 140344379214896
>>> 140344379214896
```

It would be great if someone can shed some light on why this is happening, throughout my Python experience I was under the impression empty slice returns a new object.

My understanding is that it's returning the same object as tuples are immutable and there's no point of creating a new copy of it. But again, it's not mentioned in the documents anywhere.

Comment: Related: [Since Tuples are immutable, why does slicing them make a copy instead of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34710510/7851470)

Comment: `l2 = tuple(iter(l1))` bypasses the optimisation

Comment: Noticed the [c-api for `PyTuple_GetSlice`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_GetSlice) was documented inaccurately after seeing your question. Docs have now been fixed (this was [bpo issue38557](https://bugs.python.org/issue38557)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implementations are free to return identical instances for **immutable types** (in CPython, you may sometimes see similar optimizations for strings and integers). Since the object can not be changed, there is nothing in user code that needs to care whether it holds a unique instance or just another reference to an existing instance.

You can find the short-circuit in the C code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/tupleobject.c#L771-L775).

```c
static PyObject*
tuplesubscript(PyTupleObject* self, PyObject* item)
{
    ... /* note: irrelevant parts snipped out */
    if (start == 0 && step == 1 &&
                 slicelength == PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self) &&
                 PyTuple_CheckExact(self)) {
            Py_INCREF(self);          /* <--- increase reference count */
            return (PyObject *)self;  /* <--- return another pointer to same */
        }
    ...
```

This is an implementation detail, note that [pypy](https://pypy.org/) does not do the same.

Comment: Thanks @wim. This makes sense now.
Just one thing off the topic as I'm not experienced in C. What exactly does a->ob_item do?
I tried looking up for it. but all i could understand is it takes the address of "a" and moves it "ob_item" forward. 
My understanding was ob_item holds the number of storage address that makes "1" item.
#offTheTopic

Comment: It might help to look at the typedef for tuple, [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Include/cpython/tupleobject.h#L14). So `a->ob_item` is like `(*a).ob_item`, i.e. it gets the member called `ob_item` from the `PyTupleObject` that a is pointing to, and the + ilow then advances to the beginning of the slice.

Answer (score 3):

It's an implementation detail. Because lists are mutable, `l1[:]` *must* create a copy, because you wouldn't expect changes to `l2` to affect `l1`.

Since a tuple is *immutable*, though, there's nothing you can do to `t2` that would affect `t1` in any visible way, so the compiler is free (but not *required*) to use the same object for `t1` and `t1[:]`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.* `my_list[:]` is syntactic sugar for `type(my_list).__getitem__(mylist, slice_object)` where: `slice_object` is a slice object built from `my_list`'s attributes (length) and the expression `[:]`. Objects that behave this way are called subscriptable in the Python data model see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). For lists and tuples `__getitem__` is a built-in method.

In CPython, and for lists and tuples, `__getitem__` is interpreted by the bytecode operation `BINARY_SUBSCR` which is implemented for tuples [in here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L785-L840) and for lists [in here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2779-L2832).

In case of tuples, walking through the code you will see that in [this code block](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L811-L816), `static PyObject*
tuplesubscript(PyTupleObject* self, PyObject* item)` will return a reference to the same `PyTupleObject` that it got as input argument, if item is of type `PySlice` and the slice evaluates to the whole tuple.

```c
    static PyObject*
    tuplesubscript(PyTupleObject* self, PyObject* item)
    {
        /* checks if item is an index */ 
        if (PyIndex_Check(item)) { 
            ...
        }
        /* else it is a slice */ 
        else if (PySlice_Check(item)) { 
            ...
        /* unpacks the slice into start, stop and step */ 
        if (PySlice_Unpack(item, &start, &stop, &step) < 0) { 
            return NULL;
        }
       ...
        }
        /* if we start at 0, step by 1 and end by the end of the tuple then !! look down */
        else if (start == 0 && step == 1 &&
                 slicelength == PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self) && 
                 PyTuple_CheckExact(self)) {
            Py_INCREF(self); /* increase the reference count for the tuple */
            return (PyObject *)self; /* and return a reference to the same tuple. */
        ...
}
```

Now you examine the code for `static PyObject *
list_subscript(PyListObject* self, PyObject* item)` and see for yourself that whatever the slice, a new list object is always returned.

Comment: Note that this is [different in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__), where a `start:stop` slice on built-in type, including `tup[:]`, does not go via `BINARY_SUBSCR`.  The extended slicing `start:stop:step` does go through subscription, though.

Comment: Okay, thanks will update to specify python version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this but it seems that Python provides you with a new pointer to the same object to avoid copying since the tuples are identical (and since the object is a tuple, it's immutable).